# RegisterGlobalFilters and HandleErrorAttribute not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, handleerror

After struggling with RegisterGlobalFilters and HandleErrorAttribute forever I decided to go back to the bare bones. I created a new MVC 3 project in VS10, using the template. Add a throw DivideByZeroException in the About-action and fired up the dev server. Expected not to see a yellow screen.

But I did.

Why won't this work for me?

**Update**

archil's and Adam Tuliper's suggestion kind of worked. The Error view was called.

Then I proceed to add this in RegisterGlobalFilters.

```
filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute { ExceptionType = typeof(DivideByZeroException), View = "DivideByZeroException", Order = 1 });
filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute { View = "AllOtherExceptions", Order = 2 });
```

The AllOtherExceptions view was called. Why not the DivideByZeroException view?

*The followup question has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984289/handleerrorattribute-not-working).*

Comment: A note to people debugging error handling and any other global code: recycle you webserver between compiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HandleErrorAttribute works when following conditions are met

- CustomErrors is enabled in web config
- If exception is HttpException, its error code is 500.

As in your case second condition is met, ensure you have custom erros turned on

```
<system.web>
     <customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Comment: To be honest I anticipated your response but I didn't except it to kind of work. I thought was a fallback if MVC-handlers were not registered. Please, view my update.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have custom errors turned ON in your web.config?
If not turn it on, and it should work.