# HandleErrorAttribute not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have started an MVC 3 template project in VS10 and modified global.asax.cs as such:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute { ExceptionType = typeof(DivideByZeroException), View = "DivideByZeroException", Order = 1 });
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute { View = "AllOtherExceptions", Order = 2 });
}
```

To web.config I added:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
```

Then created the corresponding views and finally added a DivideByZero-throw to one of the actions.

The result: The view AllOtherExceptions is rendered.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Much though I hate to disagree with anything Darin says, he is wrong on this one.

There is no problem with setting the properties (that's the way you are *supposed* to do it).

The only reason your original code didn't work as expected is because you have the `Order` set wrong.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28VS.98%29.aspx):

> The OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext),
>   OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext), and
>   OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext) filters run in forward order.
>   The OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext),
>   OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext), and
>   OnException(ExceptionContext) filters run in reverse order.

So your generic `AllOtherExceptions` filter needs to be the lowest `Order` number, not the highest.

Hopefully that helps for next time.

Comment: Sounds like you have a case, fear! Since Darin did solve my issue, you'll have to fight this one out with upvotes.

Comment: The funny things is that the filter is triggered if I do exception such as DivisonByZero, but not for this specific kind of Exception https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70078533/how-to-handle-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the. Any clues?

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't set properties when registering a global action filter. You could write a custom handle error filter:

```
public class MyHandleErrorAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.IsChildAction && (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled && filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled))
        {
            Exception innerException = filterContext.Exception;
            if ((new HttpException(null, innerException).GetHttpCode() == 500))
            {
                var viewName = "AllOtherExceptions";
                if (typeof(DivideByZeroException).IsInstanceOfType(innerException))
                {
                    viewName = "DivideByZeroException";
                }

                string controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
                string actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
                HandleErrorInfo model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);
                ViewResult result = new ViewResult
                {
                    ViewName = viewName,
                    ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
                    TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
                };
                filterContext.Result = result;
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then register it:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new MyHandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Comment: It worked of course. How come you can't set properties when registering a global action filter?

Answer (score 0):

Do check fear's answer below. It's certainly the simpler, if it works.

Since it came after a few weeks, this is how my filter finally spelled out, using Darins response and incorporating Elmah-reporting, with code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute/779961#779961) topic.

I still don't know why you can't set properties on a global action filter.

```
public class MyHandleErrorAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.IsChildAction &&
            (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled && filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled))
        {
            var innerException = filterContext.Exception;
            if ((new HttpException(null, innerException).GetHttpCode() == 500))
            {
                var viewName = "GeneralError";
                if (typeof (HttpAntiForgeryException).IsInstanceOfType(innerException))
                    viewName = "SecurityError";

                var controllerName = (string) filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
                var actionName = (string) filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
                var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);
                var result = new ViewResult
                                        {
                                            ViewName = viewName,
                                            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
                                            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
                                        };

                filterContext.Result = result;
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

 //From here on down, this is all code for Elmah-reporting.
                var version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
                filterContext.Controller.ViewData["Version"] = version.ToString();

                var e = filterContext.Exception;
                if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled // if unhandled, will be logged anyhow
                    || RaiseErrorSignal(e) // prefer signaling, if possible
                    || IsFiltered(filterContext)) // filtered?
                    return;

                LogException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool RaiseErrorSignal(Exception e)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context == null)
            return false;
        var signal = ErrorSignal.FromContext(context);
        if (signal == null)
            return false;
        signal.Raise(e, context);
        return true;
    }

    private static bool IsFiltered(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var config = context.HttpContext.GetSection("elmah/errorFilter")
                     as ErrorFilterConfiguration;

        if (config == null)
            return false;

        var testContext = new ErrorFilterModule.AssertionHelperContext(
            context.Exception, HttpContext.Current);

        return config.Assertion.Test(testContext);
    }

    private static void LogException(Exception e)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        ErrorLog.GetDefault(context).Log(new Error(e, context));
    }
}
```