# ViewResult for my filterContext.Result does nothing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

I have a custom exception that gets thrown in certain cases. When it gets thrown, I want to render a particular view and output it to the response.

Before I begin, yes, I have `<customErrors mode="On" />` in my root-level Web.config.

I am doing almost exactly what Darin suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8984509/718050):

```
public class EntityNotFoundHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute {

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {
        if (!filterContext.IsChildAction && !filterContext.ExceptionHandled && filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled && filterContext.Exception is EntityNotFoundException) {
            string controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
            string actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
            HandleErrorInfo model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);
            ViewResult result = new ViewResult {
                ViewName = this.View,
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
                TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
            };
            filterContext.Result = result;
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        }
    }

}
```

and registering it in FilterConfig.cs (called from Global.asax):

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {

    filters.Add(new EntityNotFoundHandleErrorAttribute() {
            ExceptionType = typeof(Inspect.Models.EntityNotFoundException),
            View = "NotFound",
            Order = 2
    });


    // Commented out just to be sure this isn't screwing it up.
    // filters.Add(new Utilities.ElmahHandleErrorAttribute(), 1);

}
```

The deal is, I can confirm that `OnException` is running as expected, but the view doesn't display. Instead, I get the unhelpful version of the yellow screen of death that tells me I should use the `customErrors="RemoteOnly"` if I want to see details.

The kicker is that all of this stuff works if I change the `filterContext.Result` to a `RedirectResult`. But I don't want to do that. I just want to write the view to the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `this.View` was `"NotFound"`. Changing it to `"~/Views/Errors/NotFound"` solves the problem.