# How to handle "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, .net-4.6.1

I've received some "generic" errors within the `protected void Application_Error()` handler on an ASP.NET MVC Framework application. The exception message is:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

There are many ways to trigger this; just one example is making a call to e.g.,

```
http:/www.mywebsite.com/http:/www.mywebsite.com/
```

I'd like to create a "filter" for this kind of exception only, and redirect or manage the request accordingly. I don't want to *disable* it, just to *manage* it. I also don't want it to fall within the generic `protected void Application_Error()` handler—or, at least, I want to manage it internally within that method, so that it doesn't get handled by e.g. my logging.

How can I manage this?

Comment: The correct response to this is to actually fix it and flag the endpoint as safe so as not to get the error. The error was added by Microsoft because so many websites by default was written to have injection-like attacks. They took the better safe than sorry approach by by default disallowing requests with form data that looks like HTML tags. The correct response to this is to go over your code, ensure you're not actually rendering it directly to HTML at any point to trigger such an attack, and then tell ASP.NET MVC that your endpoint is safe.

Comment: The error message, although it's written to be about the request that is incoming, is basically an indication that your application is not guaranteed to be written in a safe manner. You shouldn't keep this error and handle it in any way, instead you should ensure your application can handle the form data, even with things that look like HTML tags, and then tell ASP.NET MVC that it's safe.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I want to avoid it fall into the general protected void Application_Error(), where I have some other logs/stuff. I need to filter it in some way. Do you understand my need?

Comment: Yes, you should fix your controllers and endpoints so that they're not vulnerable to that kind of data and then flag them as safe, then the whole error situation goes away. Do you understand what I'm saying?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen how can I teach MVC that http:/www.mywebsite.com/http:/www.mywebsite.com/ is a correct url? :O

Comment: Noticed when I enter such a text: "#&#", it throws the error

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you already have an `Application_Error()` event handler configured, but don't want your standard logging to include this type of error, presumably because it's cluttering your logs with exceptions that you don’t intend to investigate further.

#### Background

This error is [*supposed* to be](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.util.requestvalidationsource?view=netframework-4.6.1#remarks) represented by an [`HttpRequestValidationException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequestvalidationexception?view=netframework-4.8). If this were the case here, of course, this would be a trivial problem. Based on the test case you've provided, however, you're *actually* getting the more general [`HttpException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpexception?view=netframework-4.6.1).

As [you noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70078533/how-to-handle-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the/70148234?noredirect=1#comment124117389_70148234), this is due to the .NET Framework performing validation of characters in the URL [early in the request pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147), prior to the [`RequestValidator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.util.requestvalidator?view=netframework-4.6.1) being evaluated. This may be a factor in why the `HttpRequestValidationException` isn't getting thrown, as would otherwise happen if the `RequestValidator`'s [`IsValidRequestString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.util.requestvalidator.isvalidrequeststring?view=netframework-4.6.1) method returned `false`.

#### Workaround

Unfortunately, as the `HttpException` class is used for a wide range of errors, this makes it difficult to handle. Fortunately, [as you also discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70078533/how-to-handle-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the/70148234?noredirect=1#comment124117389_70148234), you can push this validation to the `RequestValidator` by disabling the `requestPathInvalidCharacters` in the `web.config` and configuring a custom `RequestValidator`:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime 
      targetFramework="4.6.1" 
      requestValidationType="CustomRequestValidator" 
      requestPathInvalidCharacters="" 
    />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

> ***Note:*** The `requestValidationType` will need to be prefixed with its namespace, assuming it's not in your project's root namespace.

The default value for the `requestPathInvalidCharacters` is `<,>,*,%,&,:,\,?`, so you'll now need to reproduce that validation in your `CustomRequestValidator`:

```cs
public class CustomRequestValidator : RequestValidator
{
    private static readonly char[] requestPathInvalidCharacters = new [] { '<', '>', '*', '%', '&', ':', '\\' };
    protected override bool IsValidRequestString(
        HttpContext context, 
        string value, 
        RequestValidationSource requestValidationSource, 
        string collectionKey, 
        out int validationFailureIndex
    ) {
        if (requestValidationSource is RequestValidationSource.PathInfo || requestValidationSource is RequestValidationSource.Path) {
            var errorIndex = value.IndexOfAny(requestPathInvalidCharacters);
            if (errorIndex >= 0) {
                validationFailureIndex = errorIndex;
                return false;
            }
        }
        return base.IsValidRequestString(
            context, 
            value, 
            requestValidationSource, 
            collectionKey, 
            out validationFailureIndex
        );
    }
}
```

This first recreates the validation of the path (represented by the `value` parameter), and then performs the standard out-of-the-box `IsValidRequestString()` processing from the base `RequestValidator`. This will now throw the expected `HttpRequestValidationException`.

#### Managing the Exception

At this point, as noted above, this now becomes a trivial problem. As the `RequestValidator` is evaluated prior to MVC routes being parsed, you still can't use a Global Exception Filter here. Since you already have an `Application_Error()` event handler setup, however, you can manage this in your `global.asax.cs` with something like:

```cs
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

    if (ex is HttpRequestValidationException)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.StatusCode = 200;
        // Manage request as you deem appropriate; e.g.,
        Response.Redirect("~/Errors/RequestValidation/");
        Response.End();
        return;
    }

    // Your current logging logic

}
```

#### Additional Details

The `RequestValidator` gets called *at least* twice for nearly every ASP.NET request—once for the [`pathinfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.pathinfo?view=netframework-4.6.1#System_Web_HttpRequest_PathInfo) (which is typically empty) and once for the `path` ([see `requestValidationSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.util.requestvalidator.invokeisvalidrequeststring?view=netframework-4.6.1)). Every `QueryString`, `Form`, `Cookie`, `Header`, or file bound to the route will also be validated.

Microsoft tries to limit what requests necessitate validation. For instance, they don't check requests to static files. Further, parameters not bound to the route are skipped. Since potentially dangerous characters cannot be used in route parameter keys, we don't need to worry about validating those.

Further, as you noted, there's also no need to validate parameter *values* (e.g., a cookie value) for invalid path characters. Collection values will still be evaluated for the presence of *other* potentially dangerous strings—such as `<script`—by the base `IsValidRequestString()` logic.

Comment: What about this? https://owasp.org/www-community/ASP-NET_Request_Validation

Comment: @markzzz: I played around with overriding `RequestValidator`. The challenge I came up against is that exceptions for e.g. `~/http:/` or `~/<` are being thrown _prior_ to any custom request validators (or exception filters) are evaluated, and thus go directly to your `Application_Error()` handler. I suspect that's really the core issue here. I'm not certain _where_ in the pipeline these are being evaluated, but they seem to be at a comparatively low level. This leads me back, unfortunately, to my above answer.

Comment: If you set `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>` on the `web.config`, it will called before `Application_Error()`. Than, inside, you can manage them, specifying the "original" pattern as match point. Those should be the chars that .NET check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters?view=netframework-4.8 (which you can set after the custom validation has been done). What do you think?

Comment: @markzzz: That's a clever workaround! I like this because it unifies all request validation via the `RequestValidator`, allowing you to simply handle the standard `HttpRequestValidationException`. The `RequestValidator` is still called before the MVC Global Exception Filters, but that's easily managed via the `Application_Error()`. This probably adds some overhead by pushing the low-level validation down the pipeline, but that's probably an acceptable tradeoff for reliable control over this error. I've updated my answer with tested code—though, at this point, the credit should go to you.

Comment: not really. if filter "all data" now, even cookie, with unwanted char. I only need to filter the url... damn that's pretty problematic :(

Comment: @markzzz: I've updated my `IsValidRequestString` logic so that it _only_ validates the `PathInfo` and `Path` parts against the `requestPathInvalidCharacters`, skipping over collection keys or values. (Bound collection values are still validated by the `base` logic.) I've also corrected a bug where the `validationFailureIndex` wasn't getting correctly initialized. Finally, this update alleviates my previous performance concerns.

Comment: this way, all others potental danger code will be bypassed. What for example if Form contains ":"? Now it will just be ignored (due to requestPathInvalidCharacters empty). Not really sure thats a secure way :(

Comment: @markzzz: Request validation only evaluates parameters that are bound to your route. Since route parameter _keys_ can't have any of the `requestPathInvalidCharacters`, there shouldn't be a need to validate them. The collection parameter _values_ are still validated by the `base.IsValidRequestString()` for strings like `<script`. (I did initially validate the `collectionKey` as part of this, but then realized it could never be set to an invalid value due to the binding constraints.)

Comment: but the base have no requestPathInvalidCharacters. Try to filter only for ":" char the URL. I would expect the same old behaviour if I type "*" in the url... (Or in the Form). Instead it does nothing. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @markzzz: I just tested this, and any of the `requestPathInvalidCharacters` _are_ getting captured if they're in the URL, just as they did previously (e.g., using your original sample string). They're not throwing the _exception_, but only because I'm specifically managing that in the `Application_Error()` handler—which I understood to be the original objective. Only the bound parameter values of the form will be validated, which should be consistent with the original behavior.

Comment: nope. Try (as example) to put only ":" in requestPathInvalidCharacters. That char Need to be treated with special case in apperror(). But the others should be act as it did before (with app error not managed). The same for Form, Cookie, and such. If you remove the main chars in web config, it will ignore them in others parts/context (which I wont; only ":" in the url for the moment)

Comment: I think man, without overcomplicate things, to just check on app error handler if URL contains ":", and in that case just redirect and don't log :P